# How to print memory address of a list in Haskell

Tags: arrays, pointers, haskell, memory

I'm studying how some programming languages assign memory to structured data (in this case I'm studying arrays).

I'm creating the array as shown [here](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Arrays) on section 3.

```
import Data.Array.IO
arr <- newArray (1,10) 37 :: IO (IOArray Int Int) --Sets default to 37
```

And what I'm trying to do is print each element's memory address, something like this:

```
Array Start: <dec addr> | <hex addr> --Shows where the array itself is
Array 1: <dec addr> | <hex addr> --Memory address of the first element
Array 2: <dec addr> | <hex addr| --Memory address of the second element
```

The problem that I have is that I don't know how to get the memory address value for an element in Haskell.

Is there a function similar to Python's `id(object)` or Ruby's `object.object_id`?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible, but if it is, the memory address can change any time due to relocation by the garbage collector.

Comment: Yes, but I just want to print the memory address at a given time so it doesn't matter if changes later in the execution

Comment: there is a `reallyUnsafePtrEquals`, the `reallyUnsafe` makes me doubt GHC will expose this much magic.

Comment: @jozefg Hoogle 404 on `reallyUnsafePtrEquals`, google doesn't seem to work

Comment: @Jose_Sunstrider It's in GHC.Prim, is that indexed?

Comment: @Jose_Sunstrider Ah, it's `reallyUnsafePtrEquality`

Comment: @jozefg I can't find anything about that either, I think that I should give up on this, seems that haskell doesn't likes showing memory address to users

Comment: http://lambda.haskell.org/platform/doc/current/ghc-doc/libraries/ghc-prim-0.3.0.0/index.html << GHC modules

Comment: The function is [`reallyUnsafePtrEquality#`](http://lambda.haskell.org/platform/doc/current/ghc-doc/libraries/ghc-prim-0.3.0.0/GHC-Prim.html#v:reallyUnsafePtrEquality-35-) in `GHC.Prim`, and [it doesn't appear to be indexed by Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=reallyUnsafePtrEquality%23).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the following snippet which I borrowed from the [`ghc-heap-view`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-heap-view) package (it also contains an alternative solution using `foreign import prim`):

```
{-# LANGUAGE MagicHash, BangPatterns #-}

import GHC.Exts

-- A datatype that has the same layout as Word and so can be casted to it.
data Ptr' a = Ptr' a

-- Any is a type to which any type can be safely unsafeCoerced to.
aToWord# :: Any -> Word#
aToWord# a = let !mb = Ptr' a in case unsafeCoerce# mb :: Word of W# addr -> addr

unsafeAddr :: a -> Int
unsafeAddr a = I# (word2Int# (aToWord# (unsafeCoerce# a)))
```

This works by first wrapping `a` inside a `Ptr'` constructor and then casting `Ptr' a` to `Word`. Since the `a` field is represented as a pointer, the resulting word now contains the address of the object. The usual caveats apply: this is unsafe, GHC-specific, breaks referential transparency, etc.

Testing:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  arr <- newListArray (1,10) [1,2..] :: IO (IOArray Int Int)
  a1  <- readArray arr 1
  a2  <- readArray arr 2
  a1' <- readArray arr 1

  putStrLn $ "a1 : " ++ (show . unsafeAddr $! a1)
  putStrLn $ "a1 : " ++ (show . unsafeAddr $! a1)
  putStrLn $ "a2 : " ++ (show . unsafeAddr $! a2)
  putStrLn $ "a2 : " ++ (show . unsafeAddr $! a2)
  putStrLn $ "a1': " ++ (show . unsafeAddr $! a1')
```

Output:

```
a1 : 16785657
a1 : 16785657
a2 : 16785709
a2 : 16785709
a1': 16785657
```

Note that you should use `unsafeAddr` with `$!`, otherwise you'll be getting an address of a thunk that will evaluate to `a` instead of the `a` object itself:

```
  let a = 1
      b = 2
      c = a + b

  putStrLn $ "c: " ++ (show . unsafeAddr $ c)
  putStrLn $ "c: " ++ (show . unsafeAddr $! c)
  putStrLn $ "c: " ++ (show . unsafeAddr $! c)
```

Output:

```
c: 9465024
c: 9467001
c: 9467001
```

Comment: Neat idea! Possible improvements: Word would be a better final type than Int (we usually think of addresses as non-negative). If you were going to package this up you'd probably want to make a version that `seq`s the `a` before checking the address.

Comment: The pointer tags are also being printed out here, they should be masked out.

Comment: @NathanHowell Doing this in Haskell is problematic because tag width is platform-dependent. `ghc-heap-view` implements `aToWord#` as a primop for this reason.

Comment: Just what I was looking for, Thanks a lot! As my teacher told in next lesson, making this is quite hard on functional and logic programming languages due to the definition of the paradigm itself.