# Can a pure function return a Symbol?

Tags: javascript, referential-transparency

This may border on philosophical, but I thought it would be the right place to ask.

Suppose I have a function that creates a list of IDs. These identifiers are only used internally to the application, so it is acceptable to use ES2015 `Symbol()` here.

My problem is that, *technically*, when you ask for a Symbol, I'd imagine the JS runtime creates a unique identifier (random number? memory address? unsure) which, to prevent collisions, would require accessing global state. The reason I'm unsure is because of that word, "technically". I'm not sure (again, from a philosophical standpoint) if this ought to be enough to break the mathematical abstraction that the API presents.

**tl;dr:** here's an example--

```
function sentinelToSymbol(x) {
  if (x === -1) return Symbol();
  return x;
}
```

*Is this function pure?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really, no, but it might not actually matter.

On the surface, `(foo) => Symbol(foo)` appears pure. While the runtime *may* do some operations with side effects, you will never see them, even if you call `Symbol()` at the same time with the same parameters. However, calling `Symbol` with the same arguments will never return the same value, which is one of the main criteria (#2, below).

From [the MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol):

> Note that Symbol("foo") does not coerce the string "foo" into a symbol. It creates a new symbol each time:
>
> ```
> Symbol("foo") === Symbol("foo"); // false
> ```

Looking solely at side effects, `(foo) => Symbol(foo)` is pure (above the runtime).

However, a pure function must meet more criteria. [From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming#Pure_functions):

> Purely functional functions (or expressions) have no side effects (memory or I/O). This means that pure functions have several useful properties, many of which can be used to optimize the code:
>
> - If the result of a pure expression is not used, it can be removed without affecting other expressions.
> - If a pure function is called with arguments that cause no side-effects, the result is constant with respect to that argument list (sometimes called referential transparency), i.e. if the pure function is again called with the same arguments, the same result will be returned (this can enable caching optimizations such as memoization).
> - If there is no data dependency between two pure expressions, then their order can be reversed, or they can be performed in parallel and they cannot interfere with one another (in other terms, the evaluation of any pure expression is thread-safe).
> - If the entire language does not allow side-effects, then any evaluation strategy can be used; this gives the compiler freedom to reorder or combine the evaluation of expressions in a program (for example, using deforestation).

You could argue the preface to that list rules out *everything* in JavaScript, since any operation could result in memory being allocated, internal structures updated, etc. In the strictest possible interpretation, JS is never pure. That's not very interesting or useful, so...

This function meets criteria #1. Disregarding the result, `(foo) => Symbol(foo)` and `(foo) => ()` are identical to any outside observer.

Criteria #2 gives us more trouble. Given `bar = (foo) => Symbol(foo)`, `bar('xyz') !== bar('xyz')`, so `Symbol` does not meet that requirement at all. You are guaranteed to get a unique instance back every time you call `Symbol`.

Moving on, criteria #3 causes no problems. You can call `Symbol` from different threads without them conflicting (parallel) and it doesn't matter what order they are called in.

Finally, criteria #4 is more of a note than direct requirement, and is easily met (the JS runtimes shuffle everything around as they go).

Therefore:

- strictly speaking, nothing in JS can be pure.
- `Symbol()` is definitely not pure, thus the example is not either.
- If all you care about is side effects rather than memoization, the example does meet those criteria.

Comment: This is perfect, thanks! Continuing in the same line of thought, anything returning a value other than a string, number, or boolean cannot be pure, right? Given `f (x) => ({ value: x })`, `f(5) !== f(5)`

Comment: @RyanKennedy: Yes, but "*That's not very interesting or useful, so...*" …we usually bend the rules.

Comment: @RyanKennedy When you're on a VM with deduplicated strings and a garbage collector that can move objects around, nothing can ever be truly pure. If you ignore those and focus on code purity, then your part of it can be pure. This definitely isn't, thanks to `Symbol` returning a unique value every time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this function is impure: `sentinelToSymbol(-1) !== sentinelToSymbol(-1)`. We would expect equality here for a pure function.

However, if we use the concept of referential transparency in a language with object identities, we might want to loosen our definition a bit. If you consider `function x() { return []; }`, is it pure? Obviously `x() !== x()`, but still the function always returns an empty array regardless of the input, like a constant function. So what we do have to define here is the equality of values in our language. The `===` operator might not be the best fit here (just consider `NaN`). Are arrays equal to each other if the contain the same elements? Probably yes, unless they are mutated somewhere.

So you will have to answer the same question for your symbols now. Symbols are immutable, which makes that part easy. Now we could consider them equal by their [[Description]] value (or `.toString()`), so `sentinelToSymbol` would be pure by that definition.

But most languages do have functions that allow to break referential transparency - for example see [How to print memory address of a list in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18560833/1048572). In JavaScript, this would be using `===` on otherwise equal objects. And it would be using symbols as properties, as that inspects their identity. So if you do not use such operations (or at least without being observable to the outside) in your programs, you can claim purity for your functions and use it for reasoing about your program.