# Can a function which returns a new object be considered "pure"?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

Given the definition:

> A pure function is a function which given the same input, will always return the same output and produces no side effects.

Can we consider function `AmIPure` as pure function? According to definition no, but I want to make sure.

```
function Amount(value, currency) {
  this.value = value;
  this.currency = currency;
}

function AmIPure(value, currency) {
  return new Amount(value, currency);
}

var foo = AmIPure(5, "SEK");
var baz = AmIPure(5, "SEK");
console.log(foo === baz); //false
```

Comment: I'll add a question to your question. Suppose a function like this: `function returningNaN(){return NaN};`. Now, knowing that `NaN` is not equal to anything, not even to itself, answer me: is that function pure?

Comment: It depends. Do you consider "creating an object (in memory)" a side effect, and is `===` really what you want to determine "sameness"?

Comment: Related: [Can a pure function return a Symbol?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38706029/1048572)

Comment: @GerardoFurtado it gets even more interesting if you peek under the hood: there isn't a single canonical binary representation of the value `NaN`, lots of binary sequences are `NaN`. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985

Answer (score 5):

It depends on the definition of "same".

If you expect strict object equality, then only functions returning scalars (e.g. numbers, booleans, ...) could ever be considered "pure".

In general, though, that's not what you really mean: you don't usually care if you get *the exact same instance* of an object, only if it is *equal* to another according to some definition, e.g.:

- if they are strings with equal characters (`"HELLO"` and `"HELLO"`)
- if they are simple object with equal attribute names and values (`{x:0,y:1}` and `{y:1,x:0}`)
- if they are arrays with equal elements in the same order (`[1,2,3]` and `[1,2,3]`)
- ...

Comment: +1. Further, we must not mutate the objects, as then their identity would again become relevant. So immutable data structures FTW!

Answer (score -1):

Here the result you are returning from the function is an `object`. If you compare the objects it won't give true. Instead you can compare the values

```
var foo = AmIPure(5, "SEK");
var baz = AmIPure(5, "SEK");
console.log(foo.value === baz.value && foo.currency === baz.currency );
```

This should give true.

Comment: sure I understand that, but given that, is it ok to just assume that objects are equal when all of its properties (if proptery is an object then recursively) are equal? the === operator compares place in memory. So is it everything depend on thing how I define equality?

Comment: @MarcinKowal in JavaScript, two **different** objects, even if they have the same exact properties, are what I just emphasised: different.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I understand that and I am perfectly fine with that. So given that when I have any function which performs mapping from some value to any object this function would never be pure according to definition. Which makes functional programming in JS much harder.

Comment: @MarcinKowal Actually, I'd argue the opposite: to me, the function is pure. The fact that JavaScript **never** consider two different objects with the exact same structure as equals is a JavaScript idiosyncrasy, which should not avoid defining the function as pure. See my NaN example in the comments.

Comment: This post shows how to compare two objects for equality, but it doesn't actually answer the question.