# Haskell: pattern matching on Num types

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

Why can't Haskell perform pattern matching on `Num` types, without us specifying `Eq` as a type class?

For instance:

```
h :: Num a => a -> a
h 0 = -1
h x = x + 1
```

When compiling this function, `ghci` complains:

```
    * Could not deduce (Eq a) arising from the literal `0'
      from the context: Num a
        bound by the type signature for:
                   h :: forall a. Num a => a -> a
        at functions.hs:9:1-20
      Possible fix:
        add (Eq a) to the context of
          the type signature for:
            h :: forall a. Num a => a -> a
    * In the pattern: 0
      In an equation for `h': h 0 = - 1
   |
10 | h 0 = -1
   |   ^
```

Changing the function definition as following compiles and runs perfectly:

```
h :: (Num a, Eq a) => a -> a
h 0 = -1
h x = x + 1

*Main> h 0
-1
*Main>
```

Comment: It needs to be able to determine when the value is `== 0` to check against your pattern, since `0` is a `Num a => a` and not a data constructor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [Haskell 2010 Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html), the section entitled *Informal Semantics of Pattern Matching*:

> Matching a numeric, character, or string literal pattern *k* against a value *v* succeeds if *v* `==` *k*

So when you use a literal (such as `0`) as a pattern, its meaning depends upon `==` (a method of the `Eq` class).

For example, your function `h`

```
h 0 = -1
h x = x + 1
```

can be rewritten as

```
h x | x == 0 = -1
h x          = x + 1
```

You are (implicitly) using the `==` method, therefore you need an `Eq` constraint.

There are two important observations here about how Haskell differs from a lot of other languages:

1. **The notion of equality is not defined for all types.** One cannot ask whether `x == y` unless the type of `x` and `y` has an `Eq` instance.
2. **The set of numeric types is not fixed.** A numeric literal can take on *any type that has an instance of `Num`*. You can define your own type and make it an instance of `Num`, and it doesn't necessarily have to also have an instance of `Eq`. So not all "numbers" can be compared for equality.

So it is insufficient for the context of your function `h` to be "`a` has to be  a number." The context must be, more specifically, "`a` has to be a number with an equality test" to ensure that there is a way to check whether `x` is equal to `0` in order to perform the pattern match.

Comment: Now I’m curious: is there any `Num` instance *without* equality? Or are they just keeping that typeclass optional, just in case? Is that so you could, choose between different equivalence relations: `1/2 == 2/4`, or not, `Expr 1 + Expr 1 == Expr 2` or not?

Comment: @Davislor The example I've seen quoted all over the place is "you can make a sensiblish instance for functions" (e.g. https://wiki.haskell.org/Num_instance_for_functions), and functions *can't* have a good `Eq` instance. But that usually comes with the caveat "you probably shouldn't use that `Num` instance". Another possibility that springs to mind is a data type representing expressions with variables. The operations in `Num` really don't have anything to do with the operations in `Eq`, so saying when you couldn't have one without providing the other it was less useful than it is now.

Comment: But *surely* Haskell can represent equality over the Church numerals? All those professors of computer science can’t have overlooked that.

Comment: And more seriously, since GHC can pass function pointers around, I’m pretty sure there has to be a way to coerce it to implement some form of identity. But this is veering off onto a tangent. Thanks for the great examples!

Comment: @Davislor GHC does let you peer into the runtime internals; check out the `unsafeAddr` function defined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18563789/402884). But even if you do compare functions by the memory addresses at which they are represented, it still isn't a *good* equality test, because it will produce `False` in a lot of cases where you're comparing two different representations of what is really the same function. If you want  "reference equality," the proper way is to use `IORef` (which does have an `Eq` instance) or something similar.