# From Signal Int to Int in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, lava

I am working with a Haskell libraby that discribes digital circuits (Lava), its function inputs and outputs are of the type signal ( Signal Bool , Signal Int) , as far as i know there is not a function that converts from a Signal Int to Int, I know there are several arithmetic operations that we can use with the type Signal Int, but not all arithmetic operations are possible. I wrote this function that is suppose to convert from Signal Int to Int ( just for the values that I need).

```
signalInt2int :: Signal Int -> Int
signalInt2int x = case x of 
    0 -> 0 
    1 -> 1 
    15 -> 15 
    _ -> 1000
```

Just for trying I only wrote these 4 possibilities, the problem is whenever I call this function no matter what the input is, the output is always 1000. I make sure to use an input of the type Signal Int. Here is what I get.

[image]

Can anyone point out where the problem is? I will be grateful for your help.

Comment: your input `x` will never match `0` nor `1`  nor `15` because `x` is a list not a number, so you are matching against `_` which returns `1000`. Actually I think it should not compile?

Comment: You should provide a pointer to the definition of your `Signal`. It's impossible to know what it is. If I had to guess, a signal is a value depending on time (e.g. an oscillating signal), so we can't convert it to a single value. The best we could do is sampling the signal at a single point, but that's not interesting. In general there is no conversion between `F Int` and `Int`, for a generic `F`. E.g. we can not convert `[Int]` to `Int`, or `Maybe Int` to `Int`.

Comment: @chi The library name _is_ given in the question, though of course it would be better to include a link.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov I only see "Lava" mentioned above, and there are [multiple packages](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/search?terms=lava) for that, so I'm not sure. Perhaps it's [this one](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/kansas-lava-0.2.4.5/docs/Language-KansasLava-Signal.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the way integer literals work in Haskell, your code [is making comparisons `x == fromInteger 0`, `x == fromInteger 1` etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48728742/haskell-pattern-matching-on-num-types) So it depends on the way `==` and `fromInteger` are implemented for `Signal Int`.

And if you check [sources](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/chalmers-lava2000-1.6.1/docs/src/Lava-Signal.html), it turns out `fromInteger` always creates a new `Ref` and won't be equal to any existing `Signal`s.

So the question remains, how to do what you want. Pattern-matching should work, but instead of comparing with literals you'll need to go inside the actual structure of `Signal`. If I got it correct (without testing) something like this should work (returning `Maybe Int` because not all `Signal Int` signals are constant):

```
signalInt2int :: Signal Int -> Maybe Int
signalInt2int (Signal (Symbol ref)) = case deref ref of
    Int i -> Just i
    _ -> None
```